# External IP Address Changed - Tor has determined your relay's public IP address is

Tags: security, relays, circuit, firefox, vidalia

When I restart my PC I get this........
"[Wed 10. Sep 16:04:15 2014] External IP Address Changed - Tor has determined your relay's public IP address is currently 90.244.***.*** If that is not correct, please consider setting the 'Address' option in your relay's configuration.".

Although my IP address is not static and changes when my modem re-starts I have never had a problem being an exit relay.
Is my relay still working? Or do I need to add the address in relay config every time it changes?
I thought Vidalia would automatically notice the change and do this itself. I have also disabled Mcaffee net monitor for the Tor exit ports. Is this OK or should I re-enable net monitor?

Answer (score 1):

This message is for informational use. Just check if the determined address is the address you are using at the moment. If it is then your relay is working as intended. If it is not try to state the right ip address manually in the vidalia options.